# Mixed Swift / Objective-C project in Xcode 12: Why is UIImageView.setImage unknown?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have just updated from Xcode 11 to 12 and tried to compile an existing project which uses Objective-C and Swift 5.

This fails with a lot of errors which say that `UIImage` does not have a `setImage` method: `Value of type 'UIImageView' has no member 'setImage'`

This is strange because in Xcode 11 this complies without any problem. When creating a fresh new project in Xcode 12 I get the same error, but changing the code to `someImageView.image = ...` works just fine.

However, `someImageView.image = ...` in my existing project fails with `Cannot assign to value: 'image' is a method`.

**Why does the same code, which compiles in the new project fails in my existing project?**

What is the correct way to assign a new image to an UIImageView in swift?

---

```
// Fails in Xcode 12 in existing and new project
// Compiles in Xcode 11 in existing project
someImageView.setImage(someImage)   

// ==> `Value of type 'UIImageView' has no member 'setImage'


// Fails in Xcode 12 in existing project
// Compiles in Xcode 12 in new project
someImageView.image = someImage

// ==> Cannot assign to value: 'image' is a method
```

---

**EDIT:**

Following the idea of @PhillipMills I now found a `UIView` extension which implements an `image()` method:

```
@interface UIView( Image )

-(UIImage *) image;
-(void) savePNG:(NSString *)filePath;
-(void) saveJPEG:(NSString *)filePath :(float)quality;

@end
```

This is part of an extension which handles PDF Images within UIImageView. On the other hand the Swift version of `UIImageView` implement `image` like this:

```
open class UIImageView : UIView {
    ...
    open var image: UIImage? // default is nil
}
```

Both in Xcode 11 and 12 `someImageView.image = ...` fails and the command click on `image` cannot be resolved and just shows a `?`.

While Xcode 11 resolves `someImageView.image()` to `UIImageView`, the same is resolved to the `UIView` extension in Xcode 12. **Why is this?**

In Xcode 11 `someImageView.setImage(...)` is resolved to `UIImageView` while the same fails in Xcode 12.

Using the `setImage()` method in Objectiv-C is no problem both in Xcode 11 and 12.

**Questions:**

- Why is `someImageView.setImage(...)` not available in Xcode 12?
- Why is `someImageView.image()` resolved differently in Xcode 11 and 12?

Comment: Is there a reason your code has `setImage` but your error has `setimage`? (The capitalization is different.)

Comment: Does your existing project have some `UIImageView` extension that implement an `image()` function?

Comment: @atirit Sorry, this was just a typo. The code calls `setImage` and so does the error shows the method name.
@PhillipMills No, no `UIImageView` extensions. Neither in Swift nor in Objc

Comment: Command-click on `setImage()` in Xcode 11 and see where it leads.

Comment: @atirit `someImageView.setImage()` and `.image()` both leads to the Swift version of UIKit UIIMageView. However, as far as I can see the Swift code there neither contains a method `setImage()` nor `image()` but only the property `image`... I don't understand this.

Comment: I face the same issue, but I don't have override any setImage on any extension of UIView nor UIImage

Comment: Same problem here. Cmd-click in Xcode 11 leads straight to UIKit UIImageView.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that your project or 3rd party library has an extension for UIView that export a method name image. My case is that image method used to export the image of UIView. The consequence is imageview.image is becoming a method and swift automatically generate the method setImage for your UIImageView. Reason? UIImageView is a subclass from UIView. Believe me and begin to search every corner of your project, carefully check every 3rd party library, especially those that not very popular.